# How do I get the value out of the onResponse function of retrofit to return it in the outer class

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

The below is my code where im trying to return false whenever the body is not empty, but the variable blocker is not overwritten when the body has content in it. The code itself is working but it seems to not get the Code out of the onResponse method.

```
private fun checkTime(date : String, time : String): Boolean {
        var blocker = true
        val checkapt = ReservationBySalon(
            listOf(CheckApt(
                hairdresser_key = "asru6sxqrifl",
                date = date,
                status = "aktiv",
                time_from = time)
        ))
        val retrofitData = DbApi.retrofitService.validateAppointment(checkapt)
        retrofitData.enqueue(object : Callback<ReservationsList?> {

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<ReservationsList?>,
                response: Response<ReservationsList?>
            ) {
                if(response.body()?.paging.toString() > 0.toString()){
                    blocker = false

                }else{
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ReservationsList?>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("Reserve", "onFailure: " + t.message)
            }
        })
        return blocker
    }
```

Answers are much appreciated

Comment: try to change the val  to var

Answer (score 0):

You are running asynchronous code and then return `blocker` before the response is received.

`checkTime` must not return a `Boolean`. If you want to stick with callbacks instead of Flows, you can specify a callback method which is called in `checkTime`:

```
private fun checkTime(
    date : String,
    time : String,
    onTimeChecked: (Boolean?) -> Unit): Boolean {
    ...
    retrofitData.enqueue(object : Callback<ReservationsList?> {

        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<ReservationsList?>,
            response: Response<ReservationsList?>
        ) {
            if(response.body()?.paging.toString() > 0.toString()){
                onTimeChecked(false)
            }else{
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ReservationsList?>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.e("Reserve", "onFailure: " + t.message)
        }
    })
    return blocker
}
```

Comment: So when calling the checkTime method, what parameter do I pass for onTimeChecked? And also how does onTimeChecked touch the blocker variable in order to return the correct value